# Blender 2.80 Remove double vertices option gone

Tags: vertices

I downloaded the latest version of Blender 2.8 beta today.

I used to remove double vertices by switching to Vertex selection mode -> Choose all vertices -> Right click > choose Remove Doubles (in Blender 2.80 which I downloaded in April).

But I found the option - Remove double vertices gone. I switched to Vertex selection mode and press F3 to search but could not find it. Maybe it has got another name?

Comment: It looks like it has been replaced by alt M (Merge) > By Distance

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Yes, it has been rename to a more reasonable name - *Merge by Distance*.

Since *Remove Double* doesn't explain the operator well by it's own name at all. It merges those vertices which are too close to each other by a defined distance.

[image: Merge by Distance Blender 2.8 new naming]

For developers, the API does't change at all, nothing to worry about it.

[image]

### In code details

In case someone is curious about why it doesn't remove the double by exactly same position, the problem is that vertices store coordinates (x,y,z) in float numbers, a 32-bit number used commonly in computer science. It is not always precise in manipulating.

For a easy code in Python 3.6.0:

```
co = 0.1 # Create a 'co' object that gets a float value 0.1
sum_co = 0.0 # Create a 'sum_co ' object thats going to store sum

for i in range(10): # Do the block 10 times
    sum_co += co # Add co(value: 0.1) to sum_co

sum_co == 1.0 # If sum_co exactly equal to 1.0 
# Should be true in common sense since 0.1 * 10 = 1
# But the answer is 'False', the sum_co == 0.9999999999999999
```

Since this situation happens a lot, Blender can't remove the duplicated vertices by exactly same value of the coordinates. Hence, compared by a tiny tolerance is a more common way to deal with this kind of problem. Therefore, *Merge by Distance* replaces the original name.

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much for the quick answer!