# Specific vertices shoot off in random directions when bevelling

Tags: modeling, edges, geometry, bevel

I am currently trying to create a basic wheel-like shape to test out blender and work out some of the key shortcuts on Mac.

I am encountering an issue when I try to ***bevel* specific edge loops**, please see the pictures:

[image: Edge 1] [image: Edge 2]

I fully anticipate that I have some sort of geometrical inconsistency - I have tried some options from `mesh>cleanup` on the whole mesh object as detailed in [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/139733/blender-2-80-remove-double-vertices-option-gone) like 'merge by distance' or 'split non-planar faces' (I don't really actually know what that does but I hoped it might make any doubles more obvious).

The issues pictured only occur on these edges, others around it are fine

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be an easy fix, somewhere along this line my 'surface normals' got all messed up, and Blender's vertices follow their respective surface normals when transforming like in the `bevel` tool.

To resolve this problem (unless you have custom surface normals and resetting isn't an option) is to simply select the area which is not behaving as expected (in this case the edge loops and `recalculate normals`. For Mac the shortcut for this is `shift + N`.

See more about it [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/normals.html?highlight=recalculate%20normals#recalculate-normals)