# subdivision modifier doesen't smooth one edge

Tags: subdivision-surface

Hello im trying to do a character and when i add subdivision modifier one edge doesen't get smooth
[image]

Comment: You may have overlapping vertices. Check out https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/139733/blender-2-80-remove-double-vertices-option-gone

Comment: thanks but i dont have any doubles

Comment: If you upload the file to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ we can probably figure it out for sure. It could be flipped normals (select everything with A and hit Shift+N), or it could be a crease.

Comment: Face normals are inverted. Select and try Shift+N

Comment: thanks shift+n worked for me