# Inset pulling along wrong faces

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm following a PluralSight Blender fundamentals course. It's my first attempt at using Blender, love it so far!

However, during the course I have to inset some circles. This worked perfectly until I accidentally deselected the right faces. Now when I re-select the faces and try to inset them I get this weird result.
It looks like some faces are somehow connected to other faces?

It supposed to be a circle, like most of it is.

Been fiddling with this for over two hours. Any help is appreciated!

[image]

After using Clean up -> Merge by distance I get the following, interesting yet unwanted, result. It looks like still something too much is being selected.

[image]

Comment: Hello :). Have you checked for double vertices? https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/139733/78972

Comment: Thanks for your reply! That did do something, and it does get tidier. Still, no perfect circle like before :( Updated the OP.

Comment: Hey :). These could be interior faces  - You can check them through *Select > All by trait > Interior Faces* and delete them.

Comment: That was it! Now my circle is perfectly working. Thanks so much! Please create an answer reply, and I will be sure to mark it as the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like non-manifold geometry.

1. Check possible interior faces through *Select > All by trait > Interior Faces*
2. Get rid of them through *Delete > Faces*
3. Select all and remove double vertices through *Mesh > Clean up > Merge by distance*, <kbd>Alt + M</kbd>

*Remove interior faces and double vertices left behind.*
[image]