# a hole in blender how to fix?

Tags: modeling

[image]
[image]

In the edit mode everithing fine , but when i go to edit mode, smth crazy is going on 
holes everywhere and i dont know how to fix this

Comment: Put the mirror modifier before the subdivision modifier (higher in the list)

Comment: I put, but have the same ptoblem:)

Comment: @AylaStudio similar artefacts may also happen when you have doubles of vertices, try to remove them ([look here if you don't know how](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/139733/blender-2-80-remove-double-vertices-option-gone)).

Comment: Also, when using `Mirror` it's better not to have vertices on the other side (like the selected one on the 2nd screenshot). Disable mirroring to ensure that you don't have other such vertices.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/353/how-can-i-make-the-mirror-modifier-work-right/354#354 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6063/subsurf-and-mirror-modifier-creating-a-split-in-mesh/6065#6065