# Why can't I unwrap this simple cuboid mesh?

Tags: texturing, uv

I marked seams on this mesh. One side looks like this:

[image]

From the other side, there is also a seam on the short edge:

[image]

No seams on the bottom. I can easily imagine cutting this with a knife and laying it flat was it made of paper, yet blender cannot figure it out. I am getting a message:

> Unwrap could not solve any island(s), edge seams may need to be added

I also tried to add seams on all outer edges, again no effect:

[image]

So in the end I tried to split the model to have each face separately and guess what? Still the same error.

[image]

People were not kidding when they said Blender is impossible to use for new users.

So what is missing? And does this **really** have to be done manually when I just want to map a seamless texture?

The model in open scad looks like this:

```
// width and depth of the transformer base (it's a square)
baseSize = 10;
// height of the transformer base
baseHeight = 2;
cube([baseSize, baseSize, baseHeight]);
```

And here's a ASCI STL "render" of the model that can be imported to Blender:

```
solid STL generated by MeshLab
  facet normal -0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  1.000000e+00
    outer loop
      vertex   0.000000e+00  1.000000e+01  2.000000e+00
      vertex   1.000000e+01  0.000000e+00  2.000000e+00
      vertex   1.000000e+01  1.000000e+01  2.000000e+00
    endloop
  endfacet
  facet normal  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  1.000000e+00
    outer loop
      vertex   1.000000e+01  0.000000e+00  2.000000e+00
      vertex   0.000000e+00  1.000000e+01  2.000000e+00
      vertex   0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  2.000000e+00
    endloop
  endfacet
  facet normal  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00 -1.000000e+00
    outer loop
      vertex   0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
      vertex   1.000000e+01  1.000000e+01  0.000000e+00
      vertex   1.000000e+01  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
    endloop
  endfacet
  facet normal -0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00 -1.000000e+00
    outer loop
      vertex   1.000000e+01  1.000000e+01  0.000000e+00
      vertex   0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
      vertex   0.000000e+00  1.000000e+01  0.000000e+00
    endloop
  endfacet
  facet normal  0.000000e+00 -1.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
    outer loop
      vertex   0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
      vertex   1.000000e+01  0.000000e+00  2.000000e+00
      vertex   0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  2.000000e+00
    endloop
  endfacet
  facet normal  0.000000e+00 -1.000000e+00 -0.000000e+00
    outer loop
      vertex   1.000000e+01  0.000000e+00  2.000000e+00
      vertex   0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
      vertex   1.000000e+01  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
    endloop
  endfacet
  facet normal  1.000000e+00 -0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
    outer loop
      vertex   1.000000e+01  0.000000e+00  2.000000e+00
      vertex   1.000000e+01  1.000000e+01  0.000000e+00
      vertex   1.000000e+01  1.000000e+01  2.000000e+00
    endloop
  endfacet
  facet normal  1.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
    outer loop
      vertex   1.000000e+01  1.000000e+01  0.000000e+00
      vertex   1.000000e+01  0.000000e+00  2.000000e+00
      vertex   1.000000e+01  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
    endloop
  endfacet
  facet normal  0.000000e+00  1.000000e+00 -0.000000e+00
    outer loop
      vertex   1.000000e+01  1.000000e+01  0.000000e+00
      vertex   0.000000e+00  1.000000e+01  2.000000e+00
      vertex   1.000000e+01  1.000000e+01  2.000000e+00
    endloop
  endfacet
  facet normal  0.000000e+00  1.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
    outer loop
      vertex   0.000000e+00  1.000000e+01  2.000000e+00
      vertex   1.000000e+01  1.000000e+01  0.000000e+00
      vertex   0.000000e+00  1.000000e+01  0.000000e+00
    endloop
  endfacet
  facet normal -1.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
    outer loop
      vertex   0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
      vertex   0.000000e+00  1.000000e+01  2.000000e+00
      vertex   0.000000e+00  1.000000e+01  0.000000e+00
    endloop
  endfacet
  facet normal -1.000000e+00 -0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
    outer loop
      vertex   0.000000e+00  1.000000e+01  2.000000e+00
      vertex   0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
      vertex   0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  2.000000e+00
    endloop
  endfacet
endsolid vcg
```

Comment: hello could you please share your file?

Comment: is there a reason why the mesh is triangulated? Have you checked it for duplicated vertices? (https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/139736/107598)

Comment: @Blunder It is generated as such from OpenSCAD. It's a part of larger set of meshes. Checking for duplicate vertices is a good idea. I did "Merge by distance" and dragged the distance all the way until it broke the model then back, but no vertices were removed, so there are no duplicates.

Comment: @moonboots I have added both the openscad source and the STL in ASCII format, since I don't know where to upload the binary model.

Comment: When I imported STL model and Marked Seams, Unwrap works for me ... also without seams Smart Unwrap or Projection from View unwrap works for me ... I used  official 2.93 ... can you share your .blend via https://blend-exchange.com (given code copy paste into your Question via edit).

Answer (score 0):

Chipping in late as this post is the top hit on Google when I searched for a solution to a similar problem.

In my case, I needed to select all the vertices in the model before selecting unwrap. Having no points (or a random subset) can result in the unhelpful error message 'unwrap could not solve any island(s)'. Vertex selection would explain why it works for vkludu and not OP.